# Is it okay to generalize a question?

Tags: discussion

Some time ago we had the problem with a scrollbar overlaying content in IE, we found the problem and fixed it.

Later on, I found a similar question in stackoverflow. But the question is about a 3rd party framework, which is not the source of the problem.

I added an answer to the question, but I think more people could profit from the question and the answer if the 3rd party framwork would be removed from the question (the question contains it both in the title and is also tagged with the framework).

My question is: would it be okay to generalize the question? Or would that change to question itself too much?

The question is:
[Scrollbar overlay in IE10, how do you stop that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045132/scrollbar-overlay-in-ie10-how-do-you-stop-that-might-be-bootstrap/19706857#19706857)

Comment: Such a process is probably the only way to turn old, specific highly up voted questions into good canonical questions.