# Should questions receiving a general answer edit with a more general title?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026331/what-is-the-purpose-of-linking-object-files-separately-in-a-makefile/26027691#26027691) to the question “[What is the purpose of linking object files separately in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26026331/2654678)”, I observe that the question raised by the OP is actually a more general issue:

> Why do you want to write a Makefile and not write a simple shell script? In the example that you consider simple, you make no use of any feature of make[…]! You are actually questioning about the point of writing Makefiles instead of shell scripts, and I will address this in my answer.

Is it legitimate to then edit the original question title to reflect this more general issue?  I think that doing so might be useful to other Stack Overflow visitors curious about Makefiles and shell scripting.

A brief research led me to the META question “[Is it okay to generalize a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269138/2654678)” which gave a small hint that this edit could be appropriate. I therefore suggested the corresponding changes in the question but my edits were rejected.

Should I leave the question as it is now or is it legitimate to edit its title so that it reflects the more general, underlying issue there?

Comment: If I answer with "Yes" will you update the title to "Should anything happen?"

Comment: @rightfold "Yes". :-)

Comment: Why don't you add your own general question / answer then? It ought not to be closed as a duplicate...

Comment: This is a good point! Should I then add a link to my old answer or rather duplicate the old answer by answering my own question?

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald you definitely should not copy-paste. I would keep part/summary strictly answering the original question in original question and *move* the rest to new answer. You may want to link questions too (also I've not mark original as duplicate myself and let others do if deem necessary :)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Titles should be edited if necessary to best match the **question**. It's common for questions to have titles that are either much too general, or just don't describe the question very well. Editing those titles is of course very useful.

The opposite situation where titles are more specific than the body of the question does not seem as widespread to me. But when it happens, it is certainly still a good idea to edit the title to capture the content of the question as well as possible.

I don't think the nature of the **answers** should come into play when editing the title. If you decide to provide an answer that is more general than the question, that is your choice. I think it can be valuable if done well. As long as it still answers the specific question, and provides more general background/context, that's perfectly fine. The voters will decide.

In the example you gave, the question seems quite specific. The title matches the question. Other answers addressed the specific question. So in this case, I would say **NO**, you should not edit the title of the question just because you decided to provide a much more general answer.

Comment: I do not think that “provide an answer that is more general than the question” describes accurately what I did, but rather that I recognised a more general problem in the issue raised by the OP: it then seemed more useful to address that problem.  Deciding if it is more important to address the *causa ultima* rather than the *causa proxima* of a problem should IMHO not be decided by looking at the “precision” of a question.

Comment: I agree with Reto. Your answer takes a broad, wide-angled approach to answering the question. It's an interesting perspective shift to compare make to shell scripts, but it's not one that's inherent to the question, nor necessary to answer it. It's indirect. The more direct way to answer that question is to simply point out the benefits of multi-stage builds: only recompiling source files that have changed, parallelization, etc. One could write such an answer with no reference to shell scripts, so no, you should not edit the question title.

Comment: @JohnKugelman This is a fair argumentation.

Comment: So, I have took the [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293141/why-do-we-describe-build-procedures-with-makefiles-instead-of-shell-scripts](step) and asked a new question and posted an answer.

I still have to trim down my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See X-Y problem, where Y is a superset of X. I have done this a couple of times and been approved.

Comment: I fear, I am not so lucky as you are, my second attempts has been rejected!